# Do not show application version in "Program and Features" control panel

Tags: installation, inno-setup

It is possible to remove or hide `AppVersion` from installation?
I don't want to see Version of program in *"Program and Features"* after installation.

[image]

Comment: Just based on the sheer number of applications that *do* show their version vs. the few that do not, I find this a really bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set [`AppVersion`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appversion) empty (or delete the line, as the directive is empty by default).

But, then you have to set the [`AppVerName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appvername). Depending on your needs, either set it to `My Program 1.0`; or if you do not want to see a version number in the installer itself and the *Name* column either, set it to `My Program` only.

```
[Setup]
AppVersion=
AppVerName=My Program
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the directive *UninstallDisplayName* on [Setup] section.

Otherwise the default value is *AppVerName*

```
[Setup]
AppVersion=1.0
UninstallDisplayName=My Program
```