# Inno installer program name contains the version

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to create an installer for a program and have got the Inno setup creating an installer that works as expected, the only problem is that the program name displays the name I gave it followed by "version x.x" which matches the version number I gave it.

I am looking in the main script created by the wizard but can't see any parameters that change the program's name (I tried "AppName" but it's not that).

Please could someone tell me if there is a tag I need to add to the setup. The ones I have already are:

- AppId,
- AppName,
- AppVersion,
- AppPublisher,
- AppPublisherURL,
- AppSupportURL,
- AppUpdatesURL,
- DefaultDirName,
- ChangesAssociations,
- DisableProgramGroupPage,
- OutputDir,
- OutputBaseFilename,
- Compression,
- SolidCompression,
- WizardStyle.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: There is a "AppVerName" property that can be set.

Comment: What *"program name"*? where does the name with version display?

Comment: In the Apps and Features under windows settings and where I go to uninstall programs.

I have done a bit more digging and there's a "AppVerName" property (if that's what they're called) that I can use.

Comment: So are you looking for this? [Do not show application version in "Program and Features" control panel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46000300/850848)

Comment: No, it was showing in the Name column. I've managed to sort it out now. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Well, it kind of answers your question too. I've updated it to make it more clear.